# Org agenda log mode does not show DONE items in the org agenda log mode

Tags: org-agenda

org-agenda shows the org-agenda log mode. I am a bit surprised about this, because when I change the item to TODO, it will show up.

My question is, why this makes sense as a standard configuration and how am I able to change it?

Comment: Did you try `vL`? Is `org-log-done` non-nil? What is the value of `org-agenda-log-mode-items`? You can find more information about `org-agenda-log-mode` by using the following Info command in Emacs: `C-h i g(org) RET i org-agenda-log-mode`

Comment: @NickD I found   (setq org-agenda-skip-function-global
            '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo '("DONE"))) in my config. Thank you!